# Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS intermittent display glitch

Tags: graphics, 22.04, display

Since the past week, My laptop display glitches with these weird thin vertical black and white lines which seem to be the characters in the display skewed.

The glitch is responsive, by responsive I mean that when I try to move my cursor the white skewed vertical line also moves, or when I press windows the white lines move suggesting the search menu has appeared on the display.

Sometimes upon changing tabs, the glitches get fixed and sometimes it won't at all and I have to reboot. upon boot again, I see the same glitch where the dell logo is skewed and sometime it will boot properly.

here is my

**sudo lshw -c video**

```
*-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: HD Graphics 620
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   logical name: /dev/fb0
   version: 02
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
   configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1366,768
   resources: irq:129 memory:de000000-deffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff


 *-display
       description: Display controller
       product: Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445 / 530/535 / 620/625 Mobile]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 83
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       resources: irq:131 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d01fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:df300000-df33ffff memory:df340000-df35ffff
```

I have tried two solutions to no avail.

1. [Screen flicker after fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404771/screen-flicker-after-fresh-install-of-ubuntu-22-04)
2. [The monitor started flickering with weird vertical lines](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1337804/the-monitor-started-flickering-with-weird-vertical-lines)

Both didn't work.

For a video of the bug. I uploaded the bug in youtube, it isn't monitised, just for better description.

[bug description](https://youtube/XZn3H1iwlm8?feature=shared)

EDIT 1: It seems after trying the solution mentioned in solution no.(1), the screen still glitches but upon closing the lid for a minute, the glitch  vanishes and will appear again after an hour or so. But i still want a parmanent solution as it is unproductive

Comment: I’m a bit suspicious this is a hardware problem, not an  Ubuntu issue - the sometimes distorted Dell logo suggests to me that it’s not the OS.

Comment: See (EDIT 1): Since meddling something in terms of software alleviated the issue somewhat, I am more inclined to believe it is a software issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by will, i have confirmed it to be a hardware issues. If your pc glitches during the dell logo while booting up, it might be hardware problem more than software. Thnx